# Angular 7 - will removing hash on my angular app make my website SEO friendly?

Tags: seo, googlebot

I have an angular website thats been running for more than 2 years but sadly when i checked, only the homepage was indexed.

My about us, contact us page which are serving static content was not also indexed.

I just learned that SPA will have trouble being indexed by google. So if i remove the hashbang, is it going to improve everything?

Comment: Are you asking if making it so your site isn't an SPA will improve SEO?

Comment: @JohnConde i mean i will remove the hashbang using .htaccess. so my pages like https://www.example.com/#/about-us will now be https://www.example.com/about-us. will it be SEO friendly this way or will it still be the same.